# importing com.google.maps.MapView not working

Tags: android

Trying to do a map example I found here 
http://codemagician.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/android-google-mapview-tutorial-done-right/

The problem is this code. Specifically, the compiler does not seem to know what a MapView is? In fact, also applies to android.graphics.drawable.Drawable. I thought that the import statement would resolve that but must be missing some other setup step.

Any help appreciated.

```
package com.example.HelloGoogleMaps2;
import java.util.List;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class MainMap extends MapActivity
{
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     **MapView** mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
     mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

     List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
     **Drawable** drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
     HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
     GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(30443769,-91158458);
     OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Laissez les bon temps rouler!", "I'm in Louisiana!");

     GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(17385812,78480667);
     OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Namashkaar!", "I'm in Hyderabad, India!");

     itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
     itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);

     mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
 }
 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
 {
 return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your build path?

Comment: Yes, most likely you are missing the relevant jars

Comment: I checked the build path for the project and Google APIs (Android 4.0.3) and Android Dependencies are checked. A specific error in this code is "mapview cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> did you add this to your manifest under the <application> </application> tag? Did you use an avd that supports google api?

Comment: Yes, I have added the line <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> between application tags. I modified the AVD to have a target name of Google API's. Not sure if that is what you meant on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your target device when you create new project. It should be `Google APIs(Google Inc.)-API Level -`(whatever you want).

as doc says :"you must have an `AVD` configured to use the `Google APIs` target, or be using a development device that includes the `Maps library`".And make sure you have Internet Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and as MapView is not included in the default Android libraries, so you need to
specify in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

and [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) is a good place to start with google maps

are you sure you have [image: selected google api]

Comment: I checked the project's Java Build Path and Google API's are checked. Also, I checked Android Project Build Target and Google API's are checked as well.

Comment: A specific error in this code is "mapview cannot be resolved or is not a field"